# How to open a large text file in C#

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, text-files, large-files, large-text

I have a text file that contains about 100000 articles.
The structure of file is:

```
.Document ID 42944-YEAR:5
.Date  03\08\11
.Cat  political
Article Content 1

.Document ID 42945-YEAR:5
.Date  03\08\11
.Cat  political
Article Content 2
```

I want to open this file in c# for processing it line by line.
I tried this code:

```
String[] FileLines = File.ReadAllText(
                  TB_SourceFile.Text).Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```

But it says:

> Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
>   thrown.

The question is How can I open this file and read it line by line.

- File Size: 564 MB (591,886,626 bytes)
- File Encoding: UTF-8
- File contains Unicode characters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can open the file and [read it as a stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx) rather than loading everything into memory all at once.

From MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
            {
                String line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Your file is too large to be read into memory in one go, as `File.ReadAllText` is trying to do.  You should instead read the file line by line.

Adapted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28VS.71%29.aspx):

```
string line;
// Read the file and display it line by line.
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\yourfile.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {    
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        // do your processing on each line here
    }
}
```

In this way, no more than a single line of the file is in memory at any one time.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .NET Framework 4, there is a new static method on System.IO.File called ReadLines that returns an IEnumerable of string. I believe it was added to the framework for this exact scenario; however, I have yet to use it myself.

[MSDN Documentation - File.ReadLines Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

[Related Stack Overflow Question - Bug in the File.ReadLines(..) method of the .net framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304243/bug-in-the-file-readlines-method-of-the-net-framework-4-0)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenText(@"path to file"))
{
    do
    {
        var fileLine = fileStream.ReadLine();
        // process fileLine here

    } while (!fileStream.EndOfStream);
}
```