# ssis script task (vb) issues when reading large file

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl, script-task

I'm using the below code inside a ssis script task to modify the contents of a file. I'm basicallly creating 1 json document when in the file there are many jsons, one after the other.
This code works perfectly up until around a 1GB file (to read the 1GB file it's using almost 7GB memory in SSIS), after that it crashes (i assume due to memory). I need to read files up until 5GB.

Any help please

```
   Public Sub Main()

    Dim filePath As String = Dts.Variables("User::filepath").Value.ToString()

    Dim content As String = File.ReadAllText(filePath).Replace("}", "},")
    content = content.Substring(0, Len(content) - 1)
    content = "{ ""query"" : [" + content + "] }"
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, content)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `File.ReadAllText(filePath)` to read big flat files because it will store all the content in memory. I think you should use a simple data flow task to transfer the data from this flat file to a new flat file, and you can do the transformation you need in a script component on each row.

Also you can read it line by line in a script using a `StreamReader` using and write it to a new file using a `StreamWriter`, when finished you can delete the first file, and rename the new one.

**References**

- [How to open a large text file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709575/how-to-open-a-large-text-file-in-c-sharp)
- [File System Read Buffer Efficiency](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/72256/file-system-read-buffer-efficiency)
- [c# - How to read a large (5GB) txt file in .NET?](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/c-sharp-how-to-read-a-large-1-gb-txt-file-in-net)

Comment: StreamReader/Writer was the solution